# Why the difference in the results of Integrate and NIntegrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, bugs

**Bug introduced in version 12.0.0, and persisting through 13.2.0 on Windows. Doesn't reproduce on ARM Mac versions 13.0.0 and above.**

---

Calculating the integral $$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^2\log(1-x^4)} {1+x^4}\,dx$$ symbolically

```
Integrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1}]
```

> `-4 + 2 Catalan - 1/4 \[Pi] (-2 + Log[8]) + Log[8]`

```
N[%]
```

> `-0.151021`

and numerically

```
NIntegrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1}]
```

> `-0.162858`

, I obtain different numbers and the difference is too much for round-off errors. How to preclude the end of math?

Comment: This is a bug worth reporting to Support. In 11.3, `Integrate[]` returns the (complicated but) correct answer, so something happened in between that version and 12.2. (Someone else who can check 12 and 12.1 should add the requisite bug header to this question.)

Comment: Work correctly in MA 11.1.1 with the integration result $\frac{1}{144} \left(8 \left(6 \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,0,1,0)}\left(\frac{3}{4},1,\frac{7}{4},-1\right)+\sqrt{2} \log (8)-6 \sqrt{2} \log \left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)+3 \sqrt{2} \left(-3 \pi ^2-8 \pi -2 \log ^2(8)+7 \pi  \log (8)-6 (\pi -2 \log (8)) \log \left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right)$

Comment: Maple 2020.2 `int` gives the same result the the numerical one. This looks like bug in integrate.  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CurEw.png)   `-0.1628582917 + 0.*I`

Comment: @Nasser: In fact, Maple reduces the integral under consideration to the sum of other integrals.

Comment: Version 12.1 gives also: -0.162858

Comment: Version 12.0.0.0 (Mac OSX) gives the reported wrong analytical result

Comment: Workaround: `D[Integrate[x^2 (1 - x^4)^t/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1}, 
     Assumptions -> Re[t] > -1] // FunctionExpand, t] /. 
  t -> 0 // FullSimplify`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: `D[Integrate[x^2 (1 - x^4)^t/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> Re[t] > -1], t] /. t -> 0` is somewhat simpler.

Answer (score 8):

This bug was introduced in version 12.0. Please submit bug report to `support@wolfram.com` or https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Submitted. No response.

Comment: @user64494. General, you have to wait a few days.

Answer (score 4):

The integration with help of Rubi gives after inserting the limits:

```
(1/(4*Sqrt[2]))*(Pi*Log[2] - Log[(Sqrt[2] + 1)^2]*Log[2] + 
PolyLog[2, -(Sqrt[2] + 1)^2] - PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[2] - 1)^4]/2 + 
Re[4*PolyLog[2, I*(Sqrt[2] - 1)] - 4*PolyLog[2, I*(Sqrt[2] + 1)] + 
PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[2] + 1)^2 + I/1000000000000]] + 
Im[-8*(PolyLog[2, I*(Sqrt[2] - 1)] + PolyLog[2, I*(Sqrt[2] + 1)]) + 
2*PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[2] + 1)^2 + I/1000000000000]]/2)
```

which I don't know how to further simplify. The small imaginary offset in the argument of the PolyLog 'pushes' the sign of its imaginary part to the positive side. Otherwise the numeric result would be wrong.

Addendum: the imaginary part of the mentioned PolyLog is

```
2*Pi*Log[Sqrt[2] + 1]
```

so the result can be written

```
(1/(4*Sqrt[2]))*( Pi^2/3 + Pi*(2*Log[Sqrt[2] + 1] + Log[2]) - 
2*Log[Sqrt[2] + 1]*(Log[Sqrt[2] + 1] + Log[2])-PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[2] - 1)^2] + 
PolyLog[2, -(Sqrt[2] + 1)^2] - (1/2)*PolyLog[2, (Sqrt[2] - 1)^4] + 
Re[4*PolyLog[2, I*(Sqrt[2] - 1)] - 4*PolyLog[2, I*(Sqrt[2] + 1)]]
-4*Im[PolyLog[2, I*(Sqrt[2] - 1)] + PolyLog[2, I*(Sqrt[2] + 1)]])
```

2.Addendum: The last may be further simplified to

```
(1/(4*Sqrt[2]))*(Pi^2/3 + Pi*Log[2]+2*Pi*Log[Sqrt[2]+1] - 
2*Log[1+Sqrt[2]]*Log[2*(1+Sqrt[2])]-2*PolyLog[2,(Sqrt[2]-1)^2] - (Sqrt[2]+1)*
LerchPhi[-(Sqrt[2]+1)^2,2,1/2]-(Sqrt[2]-1)*LerchPhi[-(Sqrt[2]-1)^2,2, 1/2])
```

Comment: Thank you. In fact, Rubi reduces the improper integral under consideration to other integrals through `PolyLog`.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
Integrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, I, 1}]

N@%

(*  -0.162858 - 4.44089*10^-16 I  *)
```

Another way:

```
Integrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1/2, 1}]

N[%]

(*  -0.162858 - 2.28333*10^-16 I  *)
```

Comment: Thank you. It's interesting. The question arises: why `Integrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, I, 1}]==Integrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0,1}]`? The imaginary unit is a singularity (a branch point) of the integrand so the application of the Cauchy's theorem is not clear to me. Also we deal with improper integrals. The command `Integrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, I, 1}]` returns the input on my comp in several  minutes. As far as I understand it, you simply do `NIntegrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, I, 1}]`.

Comment: The same issue with `Integrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1/2, 1}]`. Corollary: this is not it.

Comment: -1. I repeat again: you calculate its numerical value in a weird  way only. The symbolic result is not obtained.

Comment: @user64494 You made a mistake.

Comment: @user64494 your downvoting is unjustified and unfair. If you omit the evaluation with `N[]`, the `Integrate[]` does return a (complicated!) symbolic result, which Michael has mercifully omitted.

Comment: @J.M.: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7guy23e1r0xo1p4/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-02-27%2019.22.44.png?dl=0)  is I obtained in 12.2.

Comment: @user, you might want to edit your question to include your (full) version number (12.2) and OS, then. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3EYm.png) is what my friend who has 12.2 on Windows got.

Comment: @J.M.: I have iust executed it on a fresh kernel. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/03t0ix4m1b4f9l7/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-02-27%2019.48.02.png?dl=0) is the result. Maybe, this is a session depending result.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely, it works when done correctly via limit:

```
f[a_] = Assuming[0 < a < 1,
                 Integrate[(x^2 Log[1 - x^4])/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, a}]];
A = Limit[f[a], a -> 1, Direction -> "FromBelow"];
N[A]
(*    -0.162858 - 5.88785*10^-17 I    *)

$Version
(*    "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"    *)
```

The `Limit` command throws a `Limit::ztest` warning though, which may indicate some trouble.

Comment: Roman(@ does not work.):+1. Thank you. `f[a_]` returns a big expression with many `PolyLog`s. I think Rubi finds that integral in such a way. Also that works with `0<a<=1` too, but Mathematica has problems with its evaluating for `a->1`: it returns `(0.08838834764831844055010555+0.08838834764831844055010555 I) ((-0.9908537560314543211012304-0.1349401132293848328673948 I) \[Infinity]+(0.1349401132293848328673948+0.9908537560314543211012304 I) \[Infinity]+(0.5388161543132108251339676-0.8424233804038929803675840 I) \[Infinity]+...`

Comment: @user64494 To quote the [commenting instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/595021): "Note that the author of the post will always be notified of any new comment. You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however, if there are no comments, or only you or the author have commented on the post so far, the `@name` will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value. (To avoid breaking sentences, mentions not at the beginning will not be removed.)"

Comment: @user64494 Concerning evaluation at $a=1$: yes, that's precisely why I used a [`Limit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) instead of simply asking for `f[1]`. Keep in mind that Mathematica returns general results that may be inapplicable on some special points, like $a=1$ in this case even if you specify the assumption $0<a\le1$.

Comment: As I understand it, `f[a_]` produces a very long expression with many compound functions. Its evaluation exeeds some internal Mathematica limitations (something like `$MaxIterations=100`) and this causes problems. Maybe, it is possible to increase these limitations.

Answer (score 1):

From `13.2.0` we see that is takes a while

```
int = Integrate[
    x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> [image: time]

and that the results agree

```
Chop[Chop@N[int] - NIntegrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1}]]
```

> [image: 0]

I am providing the analytic result as well

```
int // ToRadicals // Factor
```

> [image: analytic]

Comment: Fixed in 13.0.0, modified bug comment.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in 13.2 on Windows 10. I obtain `int = Integrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming` results in `{294.976, -4 + 2 Catalan - 1/4 \[Pi] (-2 + Log[8]) + Log[8]}` and then `Chop[Chop@N[int] [[2]]- NIntegrate[x^2*Log[1 - x^4]/(1 + x^4), {x, 0, 1}]]` produces `0.0118378`. Maybe, the result depends on a session. See https://www.dropbox.com/s/6m39559x8lia92i/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202023-02-04%2013.31.34.png?dl=0

Comment: @user64494 not sure why this is happening. on my mac it worked fine as you can see. could be session-dependent as you said, but perhaps it relates to the OS(?).

Comment: perhaps @kirma has access to windows to shed some light?

Comment: @bmf No, I don't have access to Windows, sadly. It worked fine for me on all versions starting from 13.0 on Mac though...

Could be that this is more convoluted than I first thought, but it worked fine on fresh kernels on my system. My Mac is ARM-based, by the way, and I think 13.0 was the first version with native support for ARM on Mac.

Comment: Modified the comment a bit more.

Comment: @kirma thanks for taking care of the header :-)